# Heroku - How do I install/run g++ on a dyno?

Tags: heroku, buildpack

I want to be able to call g++ from the command line in my nodejs app (as part of the server response to a POST request).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to switch from deploying with Git + Heroku stack + Node buildpack to deploying your own Docker image (which can be based on [Heroku's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack#heroku-18-docker-image)) using the Heroku Container Registry: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime